# Clear html spaces in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner webdeveloper.

I have this function:

```
function showRalColors() {
        const getHex = ral => rals[ral];
        $(".ral").each(function () {
            var color = $(this).data("id");
            $(this).css('background-color', getHex(color));
        });

        $("div.material-thumb.mini-specialColorDiv.ral").each(function () {
            var color = $(this).html();
            if (color != undefined) {
                console.log(1);
                $(this).css('background-color', getHex(color));
                $(this).html('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + color);
            }
        });

    }
```

This function work fine.  The problem is with "`&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`". Always when I run this function, I have additional "`&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`" (5x nbsp). I need MAX 5

How can I repair it?

Please help me?

Comment: remove `'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'` from your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the codes you are using is generating spaces itself so simply remove and use like below:

```
$(this).html(color);
```

and for sapcing use

```
$(this).css('padding-left', '5px');
```